# Is there any way to retrieve a RichFaces TreeNodeImpl from a NodeSelectedEvent?

Tags: event-handling, tree, richfaces, listeners

I extended the RichFaces `TreeNodeImpl` to store another piece of data that I would need when that row was selected.  When I select a node in my rich tree, I execute code in my `NodeSelectListener`.  In my listener, I want to look at the `TreeNodeImpl` from which the tree was built, but I don't know how to get the `TreeNodeImpl` from the `NodeSelectedEvent` parameter.

Is there any way to get the `TreeNodeImpl` object from the `NodeSelectedEvent`?

Thanks in advance.

Shane

Answer (score 1):

You can get that in select listener like this:

```
public void processSelection(final NodeSelectedEvent event) {
    final UITree tree = (UITree) event.getComponent();
    TreeNodeImpl rowData = (TreeNodeImpl) tree.getRowData();
}
```